# check session is about to end then show alert to user

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

can we check that if user session  set into IIS, is about to expire with in some second 
and if it is then can we show any alert or notification to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set session timeout to some value say 30 minutes. Use javascript code to detect user inactivity or idle time.

If the user is inactive for say 20 minutes, you can show him the popup or link to the user saying do you want to continue your session. If the user click the link his session will continue, otherwise he will be redirected to logout page.

[Detecting Idle Time](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

This article has very clear and good example: [Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net)

there are examples of how to alert the user, redirect to home page or extend session

Answer (score 0):

What you cannot do is know "if session is about to expire with in some second", what you can do however is redirect the user to some page when the session has ended. Add this to your Global.asax

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Response.Redirect("sessionend.aspx");//Youe page which greets the user the session is over
        }
```